# How to do spatial lookup "contained" on MultiPolygon or several Polygons?

Tags: django, geospatial, geodjango

I have a map with a lot of markers on it. And I have a two not intersecting polygons (Box). I want to get all markers which covered by these polygons.

```
qb_1 = Polygon.from_bbox((-35.19153, -5.84512, -35.24054, -5.78552))
qb_2 = Polygon.from_bbox((64.16016, 50.26125, 61.80359, 52.04911))
q_box = MultiPolygon(qb_1, qb_2)

test1 = Marker.objects.filter(point__contained=qb_1)
test2 = Marker.objects.filter(point__contained=qb_2)

test = Marker.objects.filter(point__contained=q_box)

print "Count of Polygon 1 = %s" % test1.count()
print "Count of Polygon 2 = %s" % test2.count()
print "Count of MultiPolygon = %s" % test.count()
```

But the results are:

```
Count of Polygon 1 = 4
Count of Polygon 2 = 12
Count of MultiPolygon = 237
```

Why Polygon 1 + Polygon 2 is not equal MultiPolygon ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The secret lies in the words I have highlighted (from the [geoqueryset documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/))

> contained
>
> Availability: PostGIS, MySQL, SpatiaLite
>
> Tests if the geometry field’s **bounding box** is completely contained by the lookup geometry’s bounding box

The two polygons you have created happen to be have small areas, and the multipoligon you have created also has a small area, but the same cannot be said about it's bounding box.

```
qb_1.envelope.area   # 0.0029209960000001417
qb_2.envelope.area   # 4.213217240200014
qbox.envelope.area   # 5754.726987961
```

as you will see the last one is huge in comparison an it covers a lot more points than the two polygons taken on their own. Thus the whole is greater than the sum of it's parts.

You should be able to get the actual points covered by the two polygons as follows:

from django.db.models import Q
   Marker.objects.filter(Q(point__contained=qb_1) | Q(point__contained=qb_1))

But perhaps contains_properly is what you are really looking for? But that's available only in postgresql so contains is a good substitute.

> contains
>
> Availability: PostGIS, Oracle, MySQL, SpatiaLite
>
> Tests if the geometry field spatially contains the lookup geometry.

Then your query becomes

```
Marker.objects.filter(Q(point__contains=qb_1) | Q(point__contains=qb_1))
```

Comment: Now I understand! Thank you! But how can I get the one queryset which has points are covered by Polygon 1 and Polygon 2?

Comment: Hmm it really works! I thought that | it is OR and I'ii get qb_1 OR qb_2, but it works correct as I need. Thank you!

Comment: you are most welcome. | is indeed OR in query filters and yes there is a typo in my code it should be qb_2